# Problem with tag helper and codebehind validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have 2 fields ine a model defined like this :

```
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }
```

In the view they are defined like that in the form :

```
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Image" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="FileName" />
```

All is fine so far, but when I return code behind the ModelState is invalid because these 2 fields are flaged as required (error message in the ModelState.Values list).

Any idea why. So to avoid error I remove them from the model state because they CAN BE null and are not required at all.

Any help welcome.

Comment: Pass value zero and required false .

<input type="hidden" asp-for="Image"  value="0" required="false"/>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="FileName"  value="0" required="false"/>

Comment: just required="false" doesnt work and only value="0" did, of course, in this case fields are not null so they are valid, thanks for your help, but it did not solve core problem that is field are not required bu if empty, are flagued as if